# Delphi Components for Face Identification and Tagging

Tags: delphi, image-processing, face-detection, photo-tagging

Are there any good components, free or commercial, available for Delphi (I use Delphi 2009) that will allow me to easily implement face detection and tagging of the faces in photos (i.e. graphics/images)?

I need to do something similar to what Google Picasa's Web Albums can do, but from within my application.

Comment: You are not looking for a component. You're looking for a library.

Comment: I'd prefer non-visual components that can be compiled into the code, rather than a library I'd have to link to. That said, if there was a library that did most-everything, I'd probably go for it.

Comment: No. Not yet. The closest is the fb-photo-uploader program that I mention in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703542/delphi-how-to-tag-photos-the-way-facebook-does but I would then have to translate that from Java to Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you wanted

http://delphimagic.blogspot.com/2011/08/reconocimiento-de-caras-con-delphi.html

Answer (score 3):

Did you see the SDK's that come in the answer [Face recognition Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library).

The one from nuerotechnology has an activex component that you could use.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I doubt if ActiveX will be a good solution for me, since my product is a single EXE distributable. But that answer gives me some good products to check into and get ideas from.