# Face recognition Library

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

I'm looking for a free **face recognition** library for a university project. **I'm not looking for face detection**. I'm looking for actual recognition. That means finding images that contain specified faces or libraries that calculate distances between specific faces.

I'm currently using [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) for detecting the faces and a rough [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) algorithm for the recognition. But I thought there should be something out there with better performance than a self-written Eigenface algorithm. I'm not talking about speed as performance, I'm looking for a library with better results than a simple Eigenface approach.

I took a look at [Faint](http://faint.sourceforge.net/), but it seems the library is not very reusable for my own applications.

I'm happy with a library in Python, Java, C++, C or something like that. The best thing would be if it can be run on a Windows machine because I'm relying on some external Windows-only code at the moment.

Comment: Does it need to be free for political or practical reasons? If it's a pure research project you might be able to get a free academic license from one of the commercial suppliers.

Comment: I got relatively good results with only the eigenfaces approach but it seems that a good face detection api that is free to use is something that is missing at the moment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723856

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568901/

Comment: Though perfectly acceptable in 2009, this question question is no longer considered on-topic: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.* See [What should the predefined off-topic reasons be for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185142/191410)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here is a list of commercial vendors that provide off-the-shelf packages for facial recognition which run on Windows:

1. [Cybula](http://www.cybula.com/) - Information on their [Facial Recognition SDK](http://www.cybula.com/Facenforce.htm). This is a company founded by a University Professor and as such their website looks unprofessional. There's no pricing information or demo that you can download. You'll need to [contact them](http://www.cybula.com/contact.htm) for pricing information.
2. [NeuroTechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/) - Information on their [Facial Recognition SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verilook.html). This company has both [up-front pricing information](http://www.neurotechnology.com/prices-verilook.html) as well as an [actual 30 day trial of their SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#vl).
3. [Pittsburgh Pattern Recognition](http://www.pittpatt.com) - (**Acquired by Google**) Information on their [Facial Tracking and Recognition SDK](http://www.pittpatt.com/products/ftr_sdk/). The demos that they provide help you evaluate their technology but not their SDSK. You'll need to [contact them](http://www.pittpatt.com/contact/) for pricing information.
4. [Sensible Vision](http://www.sensiblevision.com) - Information on their [SDK](http://www.sensiblevision.com/sdk/sdk.htm). Their site allows you to easily get a price quote and you can also order an evaluation kit that will help you evaluate their technology.

Comment: Thanks for the links but at the moment I need to find a free library

Comment: It may not be for face recognition *per se*, but http://numenta.com/ might be of interest to you.

Comment: you can add face.com free REST API to that list

Comment: @Omry, you should add as an answer, or edit this to add [face.com](http://developers.face.com/tools/#faces/detect)

Comment: http://www.face-rec.org/vendors/ and in general http://www.face-rec.org/

Comment: @OmryYadan *acquired by Facebook* :'c

Comment: Yeah, I know.
Facebook is actually pretty awesome :)

Comment: Microsoft Cognitive Servcies Face API-It offers face detection,recognition,grouping,verification,similar face searching,etc

Comment: http://luxand.com also has both offline sdk and web api. Offline sdk can perform better with live videos than sdks listed in answer

Answer (score 55):

### Update

OpenCV 2.4.2 now comes with the very new [cv::FaceRecognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html). Please see the very detailed documentation at:

- http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html

### Original Post

I have released [libfacerec](https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec), a modern face recognition library for the OpenCV C++ API (BSD license). libfacerec has no additional dependencies and implements the Eigenfaces method, Fisherfaces method and Local Binary Patterns Histograms. Parts of the library are going to be included in OpenCV 2.4.

The latest revision of the libfacerec is available at:

- https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec

The library was written for OpenCV 2.3.1 with the upcoming OpenCV 2.4 in mind, so I don't support OpenCV versions earlier than 2.3.1. This project comes as a CMake project with a well-documented API, there's also a tutorial on gender classification. You can see a HTML version of the documentation at:

- http://www.bytefish.de/dev/libfacerec/

If you want to understand how those algorithms work, you might want to read my Guide To Face Recognition (includes Python and GNU Octave/MATLAB examples):

- http://www.bytefish.de/blog/face_recognition_with_opencv2

There's also a Python and GNU Octave/MATLAB implementation of the algorithms in [my github repository](http://www.github.com/bytefish). Both projects in [facerec](https://github.com/bytefish/facerec) also include several cross validation methods for evaluating algorithms:

- https://github.com/bytefish/facerec

The relevant publications are:

- Turk, M., and Pentland, A. *Eigenfaces for recognition.*. Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience 3 (1991), 71–86.
- Belhumeur, P. N., Hespanha, J., and Kriegman, D. *Eigenfaces vs. Fisherfaces: Recognition using class specific linear projection.*. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence 19, 7 (1997), 711–720.
- Ahonen, T., Hadid, A., and Pietikainen, M. *Face Recognition with Local Binary Patterns.*. Computer Vision - ECCV 2004 (2004), 469–481.

Comment: https://github.com/KohrAhr/MicrosoftCognitiveServices

Answer (score 19):

[**pam-face-authentication**](http://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/) a PAM Module for Face Authentication: but it would require some work to get what you want. A quick test showed, that the recognition rate are not as good as those of VeriLook from NeuroTechnology.

[**Malic**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/malic/) is another open source face recognition software, which uses Gabor Wavelet descriptors. But the last update to the source is 3 years old.

From the website:
"*Malic is an opensource face recognition software which uses gabor wavelet. It is realtime face recognition system that based on Malib and CSU Face Identification Evaluation System (csuFaceIdEval).Uses Malib library for realtime image processing and some of csuFaceIdEval for face recognition.*"

Further this could be of interest:

[**gaborboosting**](http://code.google.com/p/gaborboosting/): 
A scientific program applied on Face Recognition with Gabor Wavelet and AdaBoost Algorithm

[Feature Extraction Library - **FELib**](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~zhuji/felib.html) refers to ["Face Annotation by Transductive Kernel Fisher Discriminant,"](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~zhuji/pdfs/tmm_tkfd07.pdf)

Answer (score 13):

I would think [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface), which you are doing already, is the way to go if you want to calculate the distance between faces. You could try out different approaches like [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) or [Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_Model). I found a page that lists major algorithms that could be used for facial recognition: [Face Recognition Homepage](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/).

Also, when you say "better performance," do you mean speed or accuracy? What kind of problem are you having? How varying are the data? Are they mostly frontal face or do they include profiles?

Comment: With performance I meed detection accuracy. 
Eigenfaces is nice but what I'm looking for is a ready off the shelf package for recognizing faces because I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I don't have the time

Answer (score 9):

If your project is on a movie or TV, or anything that has a script, it looks like you definitely want to look at the work of [Mark Everingham](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/me/) [et](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~josef/) [al.](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/). The software is [available](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/nface/), as are [the results on a Buffy episode](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/nface/buffy.avi).

Answer (score 7):

You should look at http://libccv.org/

It's fairly new, but it provides a free open source high level API for face detection.

(...and, I dare say, is pretty damn amazing)

Edit: Worth noting also, that this is one of the few libs that does NOT depend on opencv, and just for kicks, here's a copy of the code for face detection off the documentation page, to give you an idea of whats involved:

```
#include <ccv.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ccv_dense_matrix_t* image = 0;
    ccv_read(argv[1], &image, CCV_IO_GRAY | CCV_IO_ANY_FILE);
    ccv_bbf_classifier_cascade_t* cascade = ccv_load_bbf_classifier_cascade(argv[2]);         ccv_bbf_params_t params = { .interval = 8, .min_neighbors = 2, .accurate = 1, .flags = 0, .size = ccv_size(24, 24) };
    ccv_array_t* faces = ccv_bbf_detect_objects(image, &cascade, 1, params);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < faces->rnum; i++)
    {
        ccv_comp_t* face = (ccv_comp_t*)ccv_array_get(faces, i);
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", face->rect.x, face->rect.y, face->rect.width, face->rect.y);
    }
    ccv_array_free(faces);
    ccv_bbf_classifier_cascade_free(cascade);
    ccv_matrix_free(image);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it has been a while, but for anyone else interested, there is the [Faint](http://faint.sourceforge.net/) project, which has bundled a lot of these features (detection, recognition, etc.) into a nice software package.

Answer (score 4):

We're using [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV).  It has *lots* of non-face-recognition stuff in there also, but, rest assured, it does do face-recognition.

Comment: I think there is no direct algorithm in OpenCV for face recognition. Face Detection from the OpenCV Library works fine

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I confused face recognition and face detection.

Comment: Just as a side note, there is cv::FaceRecognizer now, which can be used for recognition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try open MVG library, It can be used for multiple interfaces too.

Answer (score 0):

The next step would be FisherFaces. Try it and check whether they work for you.
[Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.3247) is a nice comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you're looking for, but it may be useful to you. [Face Detection/Computer Vision](http://elm.eeng.dcu.ie/~oconaire/source/) algorithms in MATLAB.