# Eigenfaces on android

Tags: android, face-recognition

Is it possible to find a Java library for face recognition because I can't seem to find any, and the ones I found are all in c++ and in my program is already written in Java, is there any API or library in android for that since I'm developing on the Android platform?

Comment: It turned out to be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595422/face-recognition-in-java. Much better answers than my own below

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: http://darnok.org/programming/face-recognition/ (untested by me)

But if you have a library that you trust in C++, I'd suggest you use them by using the android NDK. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Wait till Q4. Ice Cream Sandwich will have face recognition apis.

Comment: Ya still waiting :(