# Face morph and recognition

Tags: face-recognition

I have two requirements:

1. members of a social network choose other member's faces and morph an average face of them.
2. The website finds other members' faces that resemble the morphed face and list up in order of resemblance.

Is there a script that can do this?

I see that http://www.faceresearch.org/demos/average does the item 1 but they don't license their technology.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably need implementations of either Eigenfaces or Viola-Jones...

Comment: Some really good resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697529/face-detection-and-comparison

Answer (score 0):

First to take average of a faces you need to align the facial features. You can look at Active Appearance Models to get that one. Once you align the faces you can get mean face. After that you can compare the faces using PCA to get the nearest match.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple library to handle the morphing in javascript, but it does not do feature detection. (in my implementation you have to choose the matching points manually).

http://peter.pisljar.si/#!/en/projects/image_morph_js

to make it work automatically you will need to recognize some points (more the better) on the face. Also for the animation to look nice the images should be of the same size, similar background ...

finding other faces that resemble your face ... that might be more interesting :)
you could try with classifiers (k nearest neighbours ?) however i am not sure how well will it actually work.

you can find a nice list of algorithms to detect facial features here:
https://facedetection.com/algorithms/

ps: another idea ... you could also just compare the facial features (something like fingerprint comparison, where it doesnt actually compare fingerprints, but just its features (line splits, short line, line exits on the same side as it enters)