# Java Face Recognition Advices

Tags: java, face-detection

I am supposed to compare two pictures whether they belong same person or not. I have not worked on face recognition in Java, so could anyone suggest me an example code or an article to do this?

Comment: The very fact that you think that java or not java is relevant for such a problem scares me quite a bit.

Comment: No, it is a project which is developed for a huge competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are aware that Java in itself doesn't have anything to do with facial recognition, and that you're hopefully asking for a Java API/library for face recognition, check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library), which lists a few options such as Cybula and OpenCV.