# php to java connector , where to find good one

Tags: java, php

I want to use the power of java as back end . I'm using legacy php front end .
I know there used to be php to java connector once but its deprecated now . 
I know there is some php - to - java connector that are using tomcat as back-end and xml protocol . its not good for me . 
is there any extension based connector ? (fast direct to JVM ).

The code dosn't related to the question , its the only way I could send it

```
public function ConnectToDb($db_name)
    {
        $SelectedDbConfig = Config::GetSelectedDB($db_name);
        DBFactory::GetDBConnection(Config::DB_TYPE_MYSQL,$SelectedDbConfig["host"],
                                                 $SelectedDbConfig["db"], 
                                                 $SelectedDbConfig["user"],
                                                 $SelectedDbConfig["pass"]);
    }
```

Comment: "the code dosnt related to the question" .. so why did you post it?

Comment: can't post question without something related to code

Comment: so you think that posting random code is the right thing to do?  bizarre

Comment: there is no other way to post abstract development related question

Comment: it happens all the time... here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the [quercus project](http://quercus.caucho.com/). Its php implemented in java and running in an application server. Maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: no , im not going to run php on java .. , its solid working application with the power of apache . i need some exit points to use java frameworks from php

Comment: ok, then i got your question wrong. So whats the level of abstraction that you want to have? Do you want to call java classes directly or do you want some protocol layer between java and php? How about writing a classical backend webservice with REST/SOAP/Hessian connector?

Comment: its to slow , i was thinking about corba backend

Comment: CORBA is a very heavy weight solution and it's somewhat dated as well. Have a look into the http://hessian.caucho.com/ Protocol. Its easy to learn and gives you interfaces based remote calls. You'll get Spring Library support on the java side as well.