# How to recognize a face?

Tags: java, image-recognition, face-recognition

I am doing a project on face recognition.To test a face we need to store it as an array of coordinates of some points.But i don't understand how we will generate points out of a 3-D face?i.e how will we get a set of points from a particular image?

Comment: Perhaps you should study some litterature on the topic

Comment: i tried to find some materials on this.what i get is image algorithms like PCA etc.I understood PCA(principal component analysis) but i want to know how will we generate the matrix on which we apply eigenvector?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [Stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or the [Area 51 proposal for Machine Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning?referrer=16aNW1mHeYaJgniERDnJDg2) if it ever becomes a live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend, you have a lot of reading ahead. http://192.9.162.55/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jaifaq.html for starters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look at [faint](http://faint.sourceforge.net/) or these other StackOverflow resources:

[Face recognition Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java

In addition, there's the [Predator project](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GhNXHCQGsM) - doesn't really help you, but you will be in awe.