# Is there a face in the picture or not

Tags: image, api, image-processing, face-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Face recognition Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library)

I'm looking for library that can identify whether or not there is a face of someone in a given picture or not. Nothing more. Has someone stumbled upon such a library?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already try that "Google" thing?

Comment: I did, only found complex facial recognition apis. Maybe I should "bing"?

Comment: Face-recognition is really complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), a C/C++ library.

There's [a tutorial](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) that explains how you can use the library in face detection.