# facial patterns recognition

Tags: design-patterns, measurement, face-recognition

I am working on a research on genetics disorders and i need some libraries or SDK or APIs that can recognize a face and take some anthropometric measurements like the distance between eyes, ear position , or some patterns like eye orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by trying  [libface](http://libface.sourceforge.net/file/Home.html) or use [Cybula's](http://www.cybula.com/) facial recognition technology.

This question feels very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library). You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Luxand FaceSDK](http://www.luxand.com/facesdk/) which detects the coordinates of facial features.