# Body and Face Detection Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In an image I want to detect only the body and face regardless of the background because I need to blur the person who is in the picture and not the remaining image.

(If possible can anyone tell using core image filters)

Please  guide me

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have a bad news for you: the `CIZoomBlur` filter **is not available in iOS** but OSX only, therefore you cannot use this filter on iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After ios5.1, using a [CIDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and [CIFaceFeature](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html) class  can be easily face recognition. 
refer a this tutorial: [tutorial-easy-face-detection](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/)

if you want ios5.1 before check the this apple sample code: [Square CAM](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Body recognition,  is you will need to use opencv library. Does not yet support by apple.
check out this pdf. this pdf also have a contents that how to opencv build for iphone. It will help you a lot.: [face detection with openCV](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fprogrammingiphonesensors.com%2Fpdf%2FChapter7.pdf)

If you are successful in face, body recognition by image. get a face and body bounds.
face and body image cropping and copy after Blur the entire image then paste it back into bounds, you seem to be.

Comment: PDF not preview.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a facial detection software - this question may help: [Face recognition Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library)