# How to detect human body by using iphone camera

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, camera, face-detection

Hi i want to detect the **human body** border while taking the photo from iPhone app.

Is it possible? if it is possible how can i achieve this? is there any third party class?

if any one knows please guide me in right way. thanks in advance.

Comment: **OpenCV** You can start with [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). Here's an [example](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big problem, too big for a SO answer. Your best bet is to follow some of the leads other people give at [Body and Face Detection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860849/body-and-face-detection-issue).