# How to detect objects from Image Processing in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimageview

I have a image and the image have in it A glass a cup , two spoon.

This image is showing on the iPad.
Now I want when user touch the spoon only, the spoon color will become green rest of the image remain same.

I have no Idea how to do this? And where to start?

Any Idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: follow this may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131768/how-to-get-a-single-entity-from-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Use CALayer, create CALayer with needed frame and add its to ImageView. 
CALayer documentation:[CALayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)