# Facial recognition Library and online Code

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Face recognition Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library)

I want to build an app. that would **recognize** the face of the person whenever I met them. I just wanted to know what Library should I use for facial recogntion . And From where Can I get the code online. I need to build the project in 2 Days.

P.S 1 : I can work for 24 h a day :)

P.S 2 : This is a part of a lager project

Comment: have you search in google for "facial recognition library"?
It seems to point here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library?rq=1 . duplicate??

Comment: @user1543957 :: Even after following the above link if you have queries mail to i9processor@gmail.com