# How to process images to start my program ?

Tags: image-processing

I want to add a part to my program that instead of typing password in it , it takes a picture from the user and and if it was the same as the user claims that picture that user before added to program , program lets user to start the program.

How can I make it with every camera  or something like kinect. give me some reference how to start to work with it. is there any sdk for it or......? is it possible to make it by c# or i have to do it in other language? i need straightforward learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use opencv. It support  C, C++, Python and Android. I am providing you some link .Hope it will help

1. http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html
2. http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/e/eb/PFC-IonMarques.pdf
3. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html
4. [Face recognition Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library)