# Face detection, Face Recognition

Tags: android, detection, face-recognition

Hi I am using google face detection API, it detects the face and draws a rectangle over the face, I want to crop the face part only and save it as image.

Is there any API available to crop the detected face.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of libraries here:

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45